# Use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit to prove that $\lim \limits _{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0) }\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Tags: calculus

My attempt:

We have to show that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$

$\left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|=\frac{y^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2\sqrt{y^2}}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{y^2\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}$ for all $y\in (-1,1)$.

Now the problem is that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}>\frac{1}{\delta}$, so I cant choose $\delta=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

To be straight, I am unable to find the corresponding $\delta.$

Comment: Hint: you should not get rid of the $y^2$.

Comment: @maxmilgram how would that help?

Comment: You replace something that tends to zero very fast by $1$. No wonder the limit doesnt work anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\frac  {y^{3}} {x^{2}+y^{2}}| \leq |y|$ so $\delta =\epsilon$ is good enough.

Comment: is that inequality valid? For example, take $x^2=\frac{1}{3}$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @mamotebang $y^{2} \leq x^{2}+y^{2}$. This implies $|y^{3}| \leq |y| (x^{2}+y^{2})$. Check the inequality again in your eample.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy , I see! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With $x =r \cos t$ and $y = r \sin t$ we get

$$\left|\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}-0\right|= r | \sin t| \le r =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$